# $f(f(x)) = \log(x) \forall x > 0$, what is $f$?

Tags: functions, logarithms

I seek a function $f(x)$ such that $f(f(x)) = \log(x) \forall x > 0$ .

If possible, $f$ should be monotonic and $\log(x) < f(x) < x, \forall x > 0$

How would I go about this? Does such a function exist?

Comment: Do you mean base-10 logarithm or natural logarithm?

Comment: @bluestool Any really, the base would just put a multiplicative constant in front. I tend to think in terms of natural logs.